# How to create a department-specific shared drive

Tags: windows-server-2008, ntfs, network-share

I'm trying to create department-specific shared drives. I'm working with a Windows Server 2008 file server and Windows Vista clients. Ideally, I'd like it to work like this:

On the file server, there exists a \Departments directory, containing sub-directories such as Marketing and Development.

Sally is in the Marketing department. On her computer, she sees T:\ as a mounted network drive. T:\ only contains the contents of \\fileserver\Departments\Marketing.

Dave is a Developer. On his computer, he sees T:\ as a mounted network drive. T:\ only contains the contents of \\fileserver\Departments\Development.

I can think of a couple ways to do this using Active Directory groups and VB scripts, but they all seem kludgey. Has anybody done this before? How would you do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical answer, for a long time, was exactly that - mapping drives via login scripts that are specified in a GPO, usually with logic in the script for determining group membership. BAT, VB, KiXtart - these are the common technologies used. You might consider it kludgey, but that has been the state of the art for a long time now, unless you've bought third-party software for this.

New in Server 2008 is something called group policy preference. Since you're using Server 08, you can use that.

Comment: Wow, I guess I'm really showing my (lack of) age. \me is a novice sysadmin.

Comment: Yep! It's in User Configuration >  Preferences > Windows Settings > Drive Maps. Thanks so much.